# Sbt native packager, push to github actions repository

Tags: sbt, github-actions

I am using sbt-native-packager, with DockerPlugin enabled

Ive set:

```
  dockerBaseImage := "adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot",
  dockerRepository := Some("docker.pkg.github.com")
```

in settings.

in my ci.yml file I have:

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: docker.pkg.github.com
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and Publish XYZ Docker image
        run: sbt x-y-z-service/docker:publish
```

but when I run push it to github, I see in logs

```
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'p' after top-level value: "404 page not found\n"
Error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
Error:      at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
Error:      at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:688)
```

in push step.
what can be wrong there ?

ps. sbt docker:publishLocal, checking locally works fine ( but locally trying to do docker:publish returns 404 also )

Answer (score 0):

ok found the problem:

```
dockerRepository := Some("docker.pkg.github.com")
```

should be:

```
  dockerRepository := Some("docker.pkg.github.com/ownername/reponame")
```